# Push notification in Windows phone 8 using Azure

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, push-notification

I am an android developer and have implemented the push notifications multiple times. Now, i tried the same for windows phone. Being a beginner to it, i am not able to get the things done.

i have followed multiple links like :

[Link 1](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-get-started-push/)
[Link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
[Link 3](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-push-notifications-app-users/)

i have my own app, and want my own server to send the push notification using azure services.

Please help.

Comment: If you follow the the link1 you should be fine. In which step you have problem on the guide?

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to send push notification to the Windows 8 Mobile Application. Language is C# asp.net.

```
var sendNotificationRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Notification URL);
sendNotificationRequest.Method = "POST";
const string tileMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                        "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\">" +
                        "<wp:Tile>" +
                        "<wp:BackgroundImage>" + "</wp:BackgroundImage>" +
                        "<wp:Count>" + "1" + "</wp:Count>" +
                        "<wp:Title>" + "Completed" + "</wp:Title>" +
                        "<wp:BackBackgroundImage>" + "</wp:BackBackgroundImage>" +
                        "<wp:BackTitle>" + "</wp:BackTitle>" +
                        "<wp:BackContent>" + "</wp:BackContent>" +
                        "</wp:Tile> " +
                        "</wp:Notification>";


byte[] notificationMessage = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(tileMessage);
sendNotificationRequest.ContentLength = notificationMessage.Length;
sendNotificationRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-WindowsPhone-Target", "token");
sendNotificationRequest.Headers.Add("X-NotificationClass", "1");
try
{
  using (Stream requestStream = sendNotificationRequest.GetRequestStream())
  {
    requestStream.Write(notificationMessage, 0, notificationMessage.Length);
  }
  var response = (HttpWebResponse)sendNotificationRequest.GetResponse();
  string notificationStatus = response.Headers["X-NotificationStatus"];
  string notificationChannelStatus = response.Headers["X-SubscriptionStatus"];
  string deviceConnectionStatus = response.Headers["X-DeviceConnectionStatus"];
}
catch
{}
```